# How to generate a text that is just under a second text in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I want to get exactly like this in html:
[image]

1 and 2 is just under the words even though the sentence's position changes like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Note: I want also save this sentence with numbers and their positions to database which is another subject :)

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Check this answer it will help you. : [https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431352/5909026](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12431352/5909026)

Comment: You need to show us the [mcve] code that you're using before we can even make a start at offering suggetions.

Comment: Why not try MathJax?

Comment: this is a very easy question. no needed any code.

Comment: How can I supposed to write a code that I don't know. I might just write this: `<p> This is a sentence </p>` which is very basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positioning and pseudo-elements are probably the cleanest solution to that. A more "dynamic" variant might look like this:

```css
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 2.5;
}

span {
  line-height: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span::after {
  content: attr(data-number);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>
  This <span data-number="1">sentence</span> has an underlined <span data-number="2">text</span>.
</p>

<p>
  This <span data-number="1">sentence</span> has<br>
  an underlined <span data-number="2">text</span>.
</p>
```

Comment: Just like what I want. Pseudo-elements is the key point and I didn't know its purpose till now. Thanks!