# How is this website performing this particular function?

Tags: html, css

I am looking at this website here, https://www.symbolab.com/
, and in particular the `matrix entry` function on it. Pressing the icon with the brackets to the left of the `H2O` icon will take you to it.

Now, you are then prompted to enter your own user-defined size of matrix. Below then in a text area then appears the blank matrix, with the predefined text fields arranged in an array.

I am wanting to replicate something similar myself, and was wondering how this site was performing this function. I am new to HTML and was wondering what components were being used here? Is the larger area that the matrix is contained in a `canvas`? Are the fields of the matrix `Input Type Text` fields? If so, how is the resizing dynamically achieved as the user enters text?

Anyone know? :)

Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

The first step when you want to know what's happening behind a website is to open the console and look at the code and scripts. I think that the textarea used into your example is a basic textarea.

If your looking for a textarea that auto-resize, you can achieve this in JS. Maybe [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17772260/textarea-auto-height) can help you.

If your looking for a way to write math formula into an HTML page, there is several solutions for you on the web. [That stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431339/how-to-write-equations-in-html) propose to use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/).

Hope it helps you a bit.