# NodeJS Regex issue with html tags

Tags: html, node.js, regex, parsing

I have never really used Regex before so I don't know much about it or how to even make one so I came here for help. The html I am trying to parse is something like this here

```
<div class="stretchgoal_goal_progress_inner" style="width:19%">
&nbsp;
19% / 100%
</div>
```

I and trying to get the 19% / 100% out of the tags and in the actual div tag the width changes with the percentage so I am lost trying to figure it out

Comment: Your question means incomplete. can you explain what is the purpose of REGEX here?  that is used to check a certain format with conditions. If you want to adjust width dynamically then set using javascript.

Comment: i am trying to parse out the 19% / 100% from within that div tag but the width that is in the div tag is the same at the 19% so when the 19% goes up the width goes up that same amount too and there is where i am lost at

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link

[How to write equations in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431339/how-to-write-equations-in-html)

Try to achieve the functionality using Javascript.

```js
var a = 19;
var b = 100;
var x = (a / b);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x+'%';
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="stretchgoal_goal_progress_inner" style="width:19%">
&nbsp;

</div>
```