# Math mode inside HTML tables

Tags: html

I would like to use math mode inside the table in HTML, how can I do that?  I tried with that, but it does not work.

```
<tr>
    <td>Mean of y</td>
    <td>7.5</td>
    <td><MATH>&plusmn 0.001<MATH></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write equations in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431339/how-to-write-equations-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

You missing ; should be `&plusmn;`

```html
<tr>
    <td>Mean of y</td>
    <td>7.5</td>
    <td><MATH>&plusmn; 0.001<MATH></td>
</tr>
```