# How we can add numerical questions from html form to php database

Tags: javascript, php, html, editor, nlp-question-answering

I am creating one Exam system in which I want to add numerical questions from html form to mysql database , how can I achieve this , I tried with some editors but did not work
attaching sample image of questions

!Thanks

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write equations in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431339/how-to-write-equations-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you will need to decide which mathematics markup language you want to use.

Some examples are [AsciiMath](http://asciimath.org/) and [LaTeX](https://www.latex-project.org/about/). You could then store the equations/questions as strings in the chosen format in a varchar column in your MySQL database.

Then you would use a library like [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to typeset the questions for displaying to the users.