# How to reduce letter spacing between div letters H,2,O

Tags: html, css

```css
  div  { 
    display: inline;

}
.sub1{
    vertical-align: sub;
    font-size:x-small;
}
```

```html
    <div>H</div>
    <div class="sub1">2</div>
    <div>O</div>
```

Problem is the letter space between H, 2(subscript), 0 renders high and I wanna compact the letter spacing more.

I can't use letter-spacing less than 1 px as it is not effective.

Comment: Any particular reason why you put each letter in a different `div`? Why don't you use `<sub>` for it? For example: `<div>H<sub>2</sub>O</div>`

Comment: `H<sub>2</sub>O` ? Why all these elements?

Comment: That doesn't answer the above questions.

Comment: @JamesC Try [some libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431339/how-to-write-equations-in-html) instead of trying it to do by yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write in one `div` and only wrap `2` in span

```css
div  { 
    display: inline;

}
.sub1{
    vertical-align: sub;
    font-size:x-small;
}
```

```html
<div>
H<span class="sub1">2</span>O
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  div  { 
    letter-spacing:-0.05em;

}
sub {
    vertical-align: sub;
    font-size:x-small;
}
```

```html
    <div>H<sub>2</sub>O</div>
```

You can use `letter-spacing` with a negative value to reduce letter spacing. I prefer to use `em` values because they are relative to font-size.

As others mentioned in their comments, it would be better to use `<sub>` instead of `<span>` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    div  { 
    display: block;
}
.sub1{
    vertical-align: sub;
    font-size:x-small;
}
```

```html
<div>H<span class="sub1">2</span>O</div>
<div>CO<span class="sub1">2</span></div>
<div>SO<span class="sub1">4</span></div>
```

I have made some minor change with regards to styling and html content